# Логируеются Win-server?

Tags: vps, windows-server

Логируется где-то подключение к Windows Server 2012? На VPSe

Answer (score 0):

Да, логируются. Серверы RDP встроены в операционные системы Windows; RDP -сервер для UNIX и OS X также существует (например, XRDP). По умолчанию сервер прослушивает порт TCP 3389 и UDP -порт 3389.